# Enabling Compiz-Fusion in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, compiz, gnome-classic

I'm using Fedora 19 with Gnome Classic, and I have installed `compiz`, `compiz-manager`, `ccsm` and all required packages, but Compiz Fusion just doesn't work, that is it has no effect.

I have tried to execute `compiz --replace` but it just destroys my desktop.

What should I do in order to enable Compiz Fusion in Fedora 19 - Gnome Classic?

Comment: have you checked the logs to see why it is crashing?

Comment: no, how can i check?

Comment: check `/var/log/messages`, try to get the error that happens with for example `compiz --replace >> logfile 2>&1 `.